# how to transfer or copy cell value to anther cell in different sheet based on cell Value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two worksheets, one called Database and the other called Project Card.

All the information for each project is in one row on the Database sheet, identified by a specific project number.  The Project Card sheet has all the information for a single project specified by the user.  The user enters the project number and the info related to that project is presented using Vlookup.

My issue is that the user sometimes needs to add a note for a specific project on the Project Card sheet and I want that note to also be listed on the Database sheet.

For example: the user enters 304 (the project number) on the Project Card sheet and, after reading the details, the user adds a note about project 304.  I would like that note to be transferred to the Database sheet in the row for project number 304.

Answer (score 0):

Because the notes entered on the Project Card sheet are only temporary, you'll have to use VBA to do this.  And it get's a bit tricky because you want to keep the note on the Database sheet even after the note on the Project Card disappears.

To do this, you'll need a Notes column on the Project Card sheet that is filled by the VLOOKUP() and another column, maybe "New Note" where the user can enter or change the existing note.

Here's some sample code that will get you started. It's only a few lines of code, and I've included comments to help you adapt it to your situation.

This subroutine monitors any change to the New Note column on the Project Card sheet and copies the changed cell over to the correct project number row on the Database sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Setup variables
    'KeyCells contains the cells that will trigger the action when changed.
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim ProjectNum As Integer
    Dim DBProjectCell As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("E2:E8")   'Change "E2:E8" to your Project Card column where user enters a New Note.
    ProjectNum = Range("A2").Value  'Change "A2" to your Project Card cell containing the Project Number.

    'Check to see if anything changed in the New Note column
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then   
        'Don't delete an existing Note when the Target goes blank
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
           'Get the Database worksheet cell containing this project number
           'Change "A11:A21 to the Database column containing the project numbers
           Set DBProjectCell = Worksheets("Database").Range("A11:A21").Find(What:=ProjectNum)

           'Copy the new Note to the Database sheet.
           'Change "J" to the Database column where the Notes will go:
           Worksheets("Database").Range("J" & DBProjectCell.Row).Value = Target.Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.  If you are new to VBA, follow the instructions on this help page for [Copy Excel VBA code to a: Worksheet Module](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html).

Comment: thank you a lot for your time. I modified the code and pasted in command button but is showing  me error   " Expected end sub" I add more end sub but still not going well.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim ProjectNum As Integer
    Dim DBProjectCell As Range    
    Set KeyCells = Range("AD46")
    ProjectNum = Range("AC46").Value
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
           Set DBProjectCell = Worksheets("Database").Range("A5:A40").Find(What:=ProjectNum)
           Worksheets("Database").Range("BL" & DBProjectCell.Row).Value = Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Comment: You have declared two subroutines in the same section of code:  CommandButton1_Click() and Worksheet_Change().  Don't do that.  You should be cautious about modifying code if you don't understand the ramifications of your modifications.  This subroutine *has to* be named Worksheet_Change to detect when the user enters a new Note.  I suggest you get it working by following the instructions above *exactly*.  Then you can try to modify it.

Comment: It's Work well. Thanks not enough to you sir. Thanks you a lot

Comment: If you found this helpful, [see this help page](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) for suggestions about how to show your appreciation.